# How do i add a checkBox near each line?

Tags: c#, winforms

int counter;
CheckBox[] _cbs;

ScrollLabel._lines contain 151l ines.
counter is int

I want that on line 0 and then each 3 lines to add a checkbox in the beginning of the line with one space to the right so there will be one space place between the text in the line and the checkBox.

Now im getting exception in the loop on the line:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.button1.Text == "stop")
            {
                this.button1.Text = "start";
                this.scrollLabel1.StopTimer();
                for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    counter += 3;
                    _cbs[i] = new CheckBox();
                    _cbs[i].Location = new Point(0, counter);
                    this.scrollLabel1.Controls.Add(_cbs[i]);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.button1.Text = "stop";
                this.scrollLabel1.MilliSecsSpeed = (int)this.numericUpDown1.Value;
                this.scrollLabel1.StartTimer();
            } 
        }

_cbs[i] = new CheckBox();
```

_cbs is null.

This is the constructor:

```
counter = 0;
            this.scrollLabel1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ScrollLabel1_MouseWheel);
            this.scrollLabel1.MouseEnter += ScrollLabel1_MouseEnter;
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            RssReader.CnnRss();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.scrollLabel1.Text = readableRss;//File.ReadAllText(@"Demo.txt");
            this.scrollLabel1.MilliSecsSpeed = (int)this.numericUpDown1.Value;
            this.scrollLabel1.YStep = (float)this.numericUpDown2.Value;
            this.scrollLabel1.Words = new List<WordColor>();
            this.scrollLabel1.Words.Add(new WordColor() { WordOrText = "scrollLabel1", ForeColor = Color.Red, ColorOnlyThisWord = true, BackColor = Color.LightBlue });
            this.scrollLabel1.Words.Add(new WordColor() { WordOrText = "using", ForeColor = Color.Blue, DrawRect = true, RectColor = Color.Black, BackColor = Color.Wheat });


            this.scrollLabel1.PopLinesOnNonBmpMode = this.checkBox6.Checked;

            this.scrollLabel1.BitmapModus = this.checkBox4.Checked;
            this.scrollLabel1.TextLayoutCentered = this.checkBox5.Checked;
            this.scrollLabel1.AdditionalLinesAtEnd = (int)this.numericUpDown3.Value;

            for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
            {
                _cbs = new CheckBox[i];
            }
```

This is how the loop in the button click look like now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    counter += 3;
                    _cbs[i].Location = new Point(0, counter);
                    this.scrollLabel1.Controls.Add(_cbs[i]);

                }
```

But all the _cbs are null inside.

EDIT**

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    _cbs[i] = new CheckBox();
                    counter += 3;
                    _cbs[i].Location = new Point(0, counter);
                    this.scrollLabel1.Controls.Add(_cbs[i]);

                }
```

Not getting null but i dont see checkBox near/in the beginning of each 3 lines why ?

Comment: Where do you initialize `CheckBox[] _cbs`?

Comment: Tim i added now to my question the code of the constructor in the end i added a loop that init the checkboxes. But i see only 150 checkboxes and _lines there are 151.

Comment: Updated my question again after initialize the checkboxes in the constructor im getting null in the button click loop code on _cbs[i].Location = new Point(0, counter); i see inside _cbs 150 indexs all of them are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_cbs` is an array which you have declared and you are *reallocating* in your constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
        {
            _cbs = new CheckBox[i]; // This line reallocates the array as a larger array each time through the loop!
        }
```

You need to define the array *only once*:

```
CheckBox[] _cbs = new CheckBox[ScrollLabel._lines.Length];
```

Then you *allocate individual checkboxes* to the elements of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++) {
  _cbs[i] = new CheckBox(); // This allocates a new checkbox for the i-th element
}
```

To place a checkbox on every third line, try something like this:

```
int lineHeight = 20;                   // pixels, set this to whatever your line height is
int checkboxInterval = lineHeight * 3; // every third line
int numCheckboxes = ScrollLabel._lines.Length / 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numCheckboxes; i++) {
  _cbs[i] = new CheckBox();
  _cbs[i].Location = new Point(0, i * checkboxInterval);
  this.scrollLabel1.Controls.Add(_cbs[i]);
}
```

Note that you only need one-third as many checkboxes as the number of lines.

Comment: Working. But why i dont see each checkBox near each 3 lines on the right in the beginning ? If i have 151 lines i want that each 3 lines to add a checkBox control on the right in the beginning of the line. So line 3 in the beginning a checkBox line 6 line 9 line 12 and so on...But it dosent work i see only one checkBox and its messy.

Comment: Updated my question once again last time. Sorry.

Comment: Checkbox.Location specifies the position of the checkbox relative to its container (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx)).  What you want is to place a checkbox on every third line, so you need to determine your line size and multiply that by three (every third line).